# RecyclerView sporadically showing "dead" items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-9.0-pie

I have a RecyclerView setup like that:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:scrollbars="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/transparent"
   app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
   app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
   app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
   app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
   app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"/>

// Linear layout manager
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

// Touch helper for scrolling
ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(touchHelperCallback);
touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

// Simple adapter
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image]

Every item has a circle that, if long pressed, changes the visualization to only allow other items to be selected.

[image]

Sporadically, and this is why I can't understand what's going wrong, the long pressed items get an overlapped duplicated "dead" item without ViewModel data that is stuck on the view. If that item gets scrolled off screen (I suppose when it's recycled) it disappears and everything seems ok. You can see it in the next animation.

[image]

This is so annoying and I've tried everything but can't track it down. Any idea?

**EDIT: New hint, it happens starting from Android 9!**